# Simulating correlated lognormals in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics

I'm following the answer in this question [How can I sample a multivariate log-normal distribution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977175/how-can-i-sample-a-multivariate-log-normal-distribution-in-python), but I'm getting that the marginal distributions of the sample data fail to have the same mean and standard deviation of the inputted marginals. For example, consider the multivariate distribution below in the code sample. If we label the marginals as X, Y, and Z, then I would expect that the scale and location parameters (implied from the sample data) to match inputted data. However, for X, you can see below that the scale and location parameters are 0.1000 and 0.5219. So the scale is what we expect, but the location is off by 4%. I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong with the covariance matrix, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I tried setting the correlation matrix to the identity matrix and then the location and scale of the sample data match with the inputted data. Something must be wrong with my covariance matrix, or I'm making another fundamental error. Any help would be appreciated. Please advise if the question is unclear.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

mu  = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
sigma = [0.5, 0.8, 0.6]
sims = 3000000
rho = [[1, 0.9, 0.3], [0.9, 1, 0.8], [0.3, 0.8 ,1]]

cov = deepcopy(rho)
for row in range(len(rho)):
    for col in range(len(rho)):
        cov[row][col] = rho[row][col] * sigma[row] * sigma[col]

mvn = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=sims) 

sim = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(mvn), columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

def computeImpliedLogNormalsParams(mean, std):
    # This method implies lognormal params which match the moments inputed 
    secondMoment = std * std + mean *mean
    location = np.log(mean*mean / np.sqrt(secondMoment))
    scale = np.sqrt(np.log(secondMoment / (mean * mean)))
    return (location, scale)

def printDistributionProp(col, sim):
    print(f"Mean = {sim[col].mean()}, std = {sim[col].std()}")
    location, scale = computeImpliedLogNormalsParams(sim[col].mean(), sim[col].std())
    print(f"Matching moments gives a lognormal with location {location} and scale {scale}")


printDistributionProp('X', sim)
```

Output:

```
Mean = 1.2665338803521895, std = 0.708713940557892
Matching moments gives a lognormal with location 0.10008162992913544 and scale 0.5219239625443672
```

Observing the output, we would expect that scale parameter to be very close to 0.5, but it's a bit off. Increasing the number of simulations does nothing since the value has converged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance matrix isn't positive semidefinite:

```
>>> mvn = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=sims, check='raise')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4542, in mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal
ValueError: covariance is not symmetric positive-semidefinite.
```

and therefore there is no distribution of data that actually has the requested covariance structure. At a high-level, consider that you are specifying *X* and *Z* to both be highly correlated with *Y* (0.8 and 0.9), but at the same time to be rather weakly correlated with each other (0.3). A detailed discussion specifically about three variable correlation constraints [can be found on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284877/correlation-between-three-variables-question).

I don't know the internals of how NumPy gets around it (you should have seen a warning), but if you check the final correlation structure:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(mvn.T)
array([[1.        , 0.79817321, 0.33343102],
       [0.79817321, 1.        , 0.74525583],
       [0.33343102, 0.74525583, 1.        ]])
```

one can see that the *X* and *Z* have lower correlations with *Y* and higher correlation with each other than originally specified by `rho`. Again, not sure how exactly the variances get adjusted, but because the covariance is impossible, NumPy can pretty much do what it wants; fortunately, it seems to stay pretty close.